# pthread condition not being satisfied

Tags: c, pthreads, multiprocessing

I am creating a multi threaded application that runs forever until the user sends an interrupt (i.e. CTRL+C), where the output_report() method is run. Here is a sample of the code:

```
void output_report(int signo) {
    printf("Exiting!\n");

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_num_of_threads);
    programClosing = true;
    while (numOfThreads != 0){
       pthread_cond_wait(&allThreadsCompleteCond, &mutex_num_of_threads);
    } 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_num_of_threads);

    printf("Closing Now!\n"); //This part is not reached

    pthread_exit(NULL); // Is this needed?
    exit(0);
}

void dispatch(struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const unsigned char *packet,
        int verbose) {

    static bool thread_settings_initialised = false;

    //Only run the first time dispatch method runs
    if (thread_settings_initialised == false){
        thread_settings_initialised = true;

        if (signal(SIGINT, output_report) == SIG_ERR)
             fprintf(stderr, "\ncan't catch SIGINT\n");

        //...    

        //Set mutex for the appropriate variables to remain thread safe
        pthread_mutex_init( &mutex_num_of_threads, NULL);
        //...

        //Set attr so threads are "Detached"
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

        //Set pthread_cond_init
        pthread_cond_init(&allThreadsCompleteCond, NULL);
    }

    //...

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_num_of_threads);
    numOfThreads++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_num_of_threads);


    //...
    int rc = pthread_create( &tid, &attr, analyse, (void *) &data);
    //...
}

void analyse(void *thread_data) {
    //...

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_num_of_threads);
    numOfThreads--;
    if (programClosing == true && numOfThreads == 0) {
       pthread_cond_signal(&allThreadsCompleteCond);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_num_of_threads);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

My problem is that when ever I use CTRL+C, the program just sort of halts (not completely exit,as the program is still running. I have to use CTRL+z to get out of it). The program outputs "Exiting" but not the "Closing now" meaning the "allThreadsCompleteCond" is not being met, but I'm not sure why.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Paul Griffiths answer I updated my code like so:

```
void exitHandler(int signum){
    programClosing = 1;
}

void output_report(int signo) {
    while (programClosing == 1){
        printf("Exiting!\n");
        //rest same as before
        exit(0)
    }
}

void dispatch(struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const unsigned char *packet,
        int verbose) {

    static bool thread_settings_initialised = false;
    int rc;

    printf("DISPATCH!\n");
    //Only run the first time dispatch method runs
    if (thread_settings_initialised == false){
        thread_settings_initialised = true;

        //Set mutex for the appropriate variables to remain thread safe
        //..

        //Set attr so threads are "Detached"
        //..

        //...

        if (signal(SIGINT, exitHandler) == SIG_ERR)
            fprintf(stderr, "\ncan't catch SIGINT\n");

        pthread_t exit_tid;
        rc = pthread_create( &exit_tid, &attr, output_report, (void *) NULL);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }

    }

    //...
    ///same as before

}
```

Now the updated code still does not even output the text "Exiting"!

Comment: `printf()`, `pthread_mutex_lock()`, `pthread_cond_wait()`, and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` are not safe to call from signal handlers. The behavior you're seeing is evidence of that. You'll need to rethink your strategy.

Comment: whats the alternative

Comment: Probably to have the signal handler do nothing but set a status variable of type `sig_atomic_t`, and have a single thread periodically check it and shut the others threads down if it's changed. In general, mixing threads and signals leads to lots of problems like this.

Comment: Do you mind if you show some code to demonstrate what you mean. I'm a bit of a newbie at both multi threading and signals. Thanks.

Comment: This link http://maxim.int.ru/bookshelf/PthreadsProgram/htm/r_40.html suggests "If your thread must manipulate shared data or communicate with other threads while it's executing its signal handler, it has a number of options."  And goes on "...  A better solution would be to forgo the idea of using the handler in the first place and, instead, call sigwait to wait synchronously for the arrival of the signal. The sigwait call either returns immediately to the calling thread because a signal is already pending to the process but blocked or suspends the thread until a signal becomes pending."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf()`, and particularly, here, `pthread_mutex_lock()`, `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` are not generally safe to call from signal handlers. The behavior you're seeing is evidence of that. It can sometimes be OK to do so, but getting there involves making sure the rest of your program can't possibly be adversely affected by doing so, which for non-trivial programs is usually not feasible.

Signal handling can be tricky enough to start with, and in general, mixing threads and signals makes things even more tricky. The general approach is to (1) only call functions that are async-signal-safe from a signal handler (you can find a list of them [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers)); and (2) do as little work in a signal handler as possible. Also you'll often need to think about (3) blocking delivery of a signal or some signals for critical sections where you don't want a set of operations interrupted by a signal whose handler might adversely interfere with those operations.

Variables of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` can be safely written to by a signal handler, so a common strategy is to have your signal handler do nothing but set such a variable, which your main program then periodically checks. For instance:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t im_done = 0;

void handler(int signum)
{
    im_done = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    /*  Do init stuff and register your signal handler  */

    while ( !im_done ) {

       /*  Do your main work here  */

    }

    /*  Clean up and get ready to exit here  */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your new code doesn't seem to call `output_report()` anywhere, so obviously you'll never see the effects of `printf("Exiting!\n");` `output_report()` itself still looks like it's written to be a signal handler, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Sorry I write it wrong, but same result. It still dosen't work!.The   printf("Exiting!\n"); dosen't even run!

Comment: OK, well you'll need to sit down and think about it, basically design and then debug your program. Posting little snippets of it here and saying that it doesn't work isn't going to make it start working.

Comment: Sorted it. It was just that the code inside the while loop should have gone out side the while loop. Man I need sleep!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.